# PostgreSQL: differentiating between a bad query and lost connection in C API

Tags: c, postgresql, error-handling, database-connection

From what I can tell, if make a bad query or I restart the server while a connection is open, in both cases `PQresultStatus()` will return `PGRES_FATAL_ERROR` (handling the result of `PQexec`). I'd rather know the difference because I'm working on a retry mechanism. Is that possible?

`PQstatus()` *looks* like it's the answer, and from my tests it seems like it is, but the [documenation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-status.html) is a bit mealy-mouthed about its reliability.

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.4 on Debian 8.2.

Comment: In case of `PGRES_FATAL_ERROR` you just need to use for example the contents of [`PG_DIAG_SQLSTATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/libpq-exec.html) from `PQresultErrorField`

Comment: And if `PQstatus` returns `CONNECTION_BAD` then you know *for sure* that the connection has gone

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Good find on the `PG_DIAG_SQLSTATE`, but like I said about `PQstatus()`: even the PostgreSQL guys don't seem confident about it. It seems the class of error I'm looking for is "57"

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Oh, and I don't suppose you know what I'm supposed to do w/the return value when I'm done? They don't say whether or not I should free it. Maybe it's just a pointer to a static?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is a static one

Comment: It's part of the `PGresult` and is freed by `PQclear`

Comment: @CraigRinger Could be. I didn't do anything w/the pointer that was returned after I was done w/it, and valgrind reported no memory leaks